# Pass condition as argument to an OpenCL kernel

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, gpu, opencl

I'm trying to write an OpenCL kernel that takes a condition, i.e., a boolean value, as an argument. My objective with this is to write a kernel that behaves in the following way:

```cpp
__kernel void operation(
    __global double *vec,
    const bool condition,  // is this possible?
    const int n)
{
    // ...
    if(condition){
        // do this ...
    }
    else{
        // do that ...
    }
}
```

I've found this [thread](https://community.amd.com/t5/archives-discussions/passing-cl-bool-as-kernel-argument/m-p/263011) that says it is not possible to do what I want, but the discussion is a bit outdated and I was wondering if anything has changed.

So this is basically it. I'm completely open for suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can do exactly that. However `bool` (1-bit) is not allowed as kernel parameter. You have to use `char` (8-bit) or `int` (32-bit) instead as data type for the `condition` variable. If you set the `condition` value to `0` (false) or `1` (true), you can just plug it into the `if(condition)` as is.

I assume `condition` in your case is the same value for all threads. For performance reasons, I would advise to make two separate kernels, one for the `if` branch and one for the `else` branch, and move the `condition` to the C++ side to enqueue either of the two kernels.